# stress testing Darwin streaming server and vlc

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, video-streaming

I have Darwin streaming Server and VLC installed on different virtual machines.
What i am trying to do is stress test/benchmark both from a third virtual machine. This is a preliminary part of a project i am working on.

The idea is to check service speed/maybe quality when i send 2-10-100 rtsp requests for one file then the same thing for 5 files...and so on

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use VLC or openRTSP. You can write a shell script to open up all 100 connections.

- http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help
- http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/

Comment: Thank you. openRTSP -Q /rstp://<url>/playlist.sdp does the trick.
All you have to do next is redirect what would be shown on terminal to a file and bingo.